# Model for spatial distribution of resources in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, location-allocation

I'm looking into a way to calculate the performance of each shop (funeral directors) based on resources available (funerals in last 5 years).
Please see image attached, numbers are total funerals into each zone and points are existing funeral directors.
Basically trying to allocate each resource into each funeral based on location (mostly proximity) and not counting twice a resource.

I'm working with PostgreSQL/PostGIS (v10-11) and can work with QGIS and ArcGIS.

Open to previous experiences and suggestions.

[image: Resources distribution]